# How to access the textinput from popup window in python using kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to create a textinput and access the text the user input and put it into an if statement. However, when I enter in the correct word into the textinput, the if statement stills remains false.

```
def passer(self, text1 , text2):
    box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=(10))
    box.add_widget(Label(text="Please Enter Admin Password: "))
    self.txtpswd = TextInput(text='test',multiline=False)
    box.add_widget(self.txtpswd)
    btn1 = Button(text="Enter",size_hint=(0.5, 0.5))
    btn2 = Button(text="Cancel",size_hint=(0.5, 0.5))
    box.add_widget(btn1)
    box.add_widget(btn2)

    popup = Popup(title='', title_size=(30),
                  title_align='center', content=box,
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400),
                  auto_dismiss=True)
    if self.txtpswd.text == "test":
        Alert(title='Admin Password', text='Password Accepted')
        self.manager.get_screen('custom').add_hours(text1, text2)
        popup.dismiss()

    if self.txtpswd.text != "test":
        Alert(title='Admin Password', text='Invalid Password')
        popup.dismiss()


    btn2.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)

    popup.open()
```

I expected the if statement to result as true when I entered the right word, but it always return false, and the popup window does not even close.

Comment: Did you bind `btn1` to a callback method to check the password?

Comment: o no, let me try rn

Comment: Your code executes sequentially, from top to bottom. That is `popup` is created (but not opened), your `if` statements are executed and `popup.dismiss()` will be called by one or the other `if` block (but the `popup` has not yet been opened, so dismiss will have no effect), then your `btn2` is bound, then the `popup` is opened at the end of your posted code. So, the only way to dismiss your `popup` would be to click `btn2`.